# Unresponsive UI While Waiting

Tags: c#, .net, http, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013

Final edit: Problem turned out to be unrelated to this async implementation. The first answer helped me move stuff around enough to look at the issue with a fresh set of eyes. Thanks, guys.

I'm talking with an IP camera in my app, both through httpclient (to request and receive the image) and a websocket (via websocket-sharp, to receive data).

Right now I'm just opening the websocket and asking for one image (loops will come later). Asking for the image is the last thing I do.

When I define the request for the image as

```
string picloc = "[redacted]";
Stream imgstream = await client.GetStreamAsync(picloc).ConfigureAwait(false);
Bitmap blah2 = new Bitmap(imgstream);
BMPReadyEventArgs args = new BMPReadyEventArgs();
args.BMP = blah2;
BitmapReady(this, args);
```

the app runs through all the code and freezes up. If I leave the ConfigureAwait term off, the await will surrender control back to the UI code, it will reach the end of said code, freeze for a couple seconds and then load the image.

With configureawait(false) on there it will load the image and then freeze up. I think that the stream I get from the request starts immediately so if it doesn't have to wait for context (?) it essentially runs synchronously. To be honest, I still don't really understand what configureawait actually does, or what the context people talk about actually means, but this behavior makes me think that the UI freezing has nothing to do with the async nature of the code.

I can't see the debugger jumping to an unexpected place by stepping through with F11 (though this seems to have some shortcomings when used with asynchronous code), it really does seem to just reach the end of the code and freeze up for a couple of seconds.

This leads me to a couple questions.

Will the UI always freeze up when the end of code is reached and, if so, do I need to make some sort of UI refresh ticker?

And, alternatively but more nebulously,

Is there an issue with my async implementation that could be causing this freeze?

Edit: Complete method:

```
public async void DownloadJPG()
    {
        string picloc = "[redacted]";
        Stream imgstream = await client.GetStreamAsync(picloc).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Bitmap blah2 = new Bitmap(imgstream);
        BMPReadyEventArgs args = new BMPReadyEventArgs();
        args.BMP = blah2;
        BitmapReady(this, args);
    }
```

called from

```
private async void HoldingPattern()
    {
        textBox1.Text = wsmanager.passer;
        connector.BitmapReady += (sender, e) =>
            pictureBox1.Image = e.BMP;

        connector.DownloadJPG();
    }
```

edit2: event handler:

```
public event EventHandler<BMPReadyEventArgs> BitmapReady;
```

BMPReadyEventArgs

```
class BMPReadyEventArgs:EventArgs
{
    public Bitmap BMP {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Please show the complete method and how you are calling it

Comment: I don't think you've shown enough code for anyone to help.  For example, the call to `BitmapReady` appears to be raising an event, but you haven't show the event handler or where that event handler is located.  If it's running on the UI thread, could it be the cause of your  freezing UI?  If so, does it need to be asynchronous as well?

Comment: But where is the code that runs when the `BitmapReady` handler is raised (i. e. the subscriber code)?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway the subscriber code is in HoldingPattern(). By my understanding of asynchronous coding (and I am still a very undeveloped neophyte), I shouldn't call DownloadJPG with await, as then the UI (top-level) code would pause until DownloadJPG returns a bitmap instead of an event.

Comment: Sorry, I just missed that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is way to complicate

```
public async Task<Image> DownloadJPGAsync()
{
    string picloc = "[redacted]";
    Stream imgstream = await client.GetStreamAsync(picloc).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Bitmap blah2 = new Bitmap(imgstream);
    return blah2;
}
```

Now from an async event handler

```
public async void Button1_Click()
{
    var image = await connector.DownloadJPGAsync();
    pictureBox1.Image = image;
}
```

Comment: The task will get the image from the camera and convert it to a bitmap, but stops before returning it. I'm not sure why it isn't returning the bitmap, but I digress. Even if it did work, this is not how I want to structure my app, as I want to handle the fetching of bitmaps separately from the UI (I know I'm asking my webclient handler to fetch it from UI, but that will be changed down the road). Even if I did want to call it directly in my UI thread, as I mentioned in a comment on my original post, await in the UI thread probably isn't best as it will freeze the UI while waiting.

Comment: Sorry, I simply forgot to replace [redacted] with the actual path. The task works, but does have the issue of freezing the UI thread. It seems to be due to the await in the UI thread now, though, instead of an unknown. I'll try shifting the task call to where it belongs and report back.

Comment: The "await in the UI thread" is there to **not block** the UIThread! Are you sure you have ConfigureAwait(false) after GetStreamAsync(...) ? Otherwise creation of Bitmap will happen on UIThread and the creation will take some time